# What does Unix "lunch" command do?

Tags: linux, unix

man lunch and lunch --help both return nothing
Googling for unix lunch command, I also find nothing

I am assuming it is custom. How do I go about finding its location and what it does?

Answer (score 5):

I did not have it installed:

```
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$ lunch
The program 'lunch' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-lunch
aularon@aularon-laptop:~$
```

From package info (`apt-cache show python-lunch`):

> Lunch is a simple distributed process launcher and manager for
>   GNU/Linux.  .  With Lunch, one can launch software processes on
>   several different computers  and make sure they keep running. This
>   software was created to suit the needs  of new media artists for live
>   performances and interactive installations.  It respawns the software
>   that crash and provides a mean to manage  dependencies between running
>   processes.  .  This package provides the lunch library for Python. as
>   well as the  command-line lunch utility which can be invoked with a
>   GTK+ user interface.

Answer (score 2):

It is the [Lunch Distributed Process Manager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/lunch.1.html).